# split file using awk

Tags: awk, split

I tried to split my file based on first column and write to separate txt file using the command found in one of the threads and it shows the following error:

```
awk '{print > $1".txt"}' TS129.txt 
awk: syntax error at source line 1
context is
{print > >>>  $1".txt" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

It looks a simple error but it doesn't strike to my mind. Could someone help to fix this?

Comment: The syntax works to me on `mawk 1.3.3`. Could you past some lines of TS129.txt? Maybe the first field has some strange characters that make awk become crazy while processing.

Comment: With some awks, to the right of the `>` you need a variable or a literal string. Try `{f = $1 ".txt"; print > f}`

Comment: I tried using your suggestion. `sed 1d TS129.txt | awk -F '\t' '{ f=$1 ".txt";print > f }'
awk: PN01-0647_83096.KC_ref_129_GTS_CytoHD_na32.1.cyhd.cychp.txt makes too many open files
 input record number 1430, file 
 source line number 1`

Comment: The issue is that you MUST parenthesize anything on the right of an output redirection operator. `print > $1".txt"` produces undefined behavior as it can be interpreted by any given awk as `print > $1; ".txt"` or `print > ($1".txt")`. If the latter is what you want then that's what you need to write. glenn is mistaken - you never NEED a variable or literal string, you just always need to parenthesize if you're using concatenation.

Comment: @EdMorton Well!! i tried using `awk -F '\t' '{ print > ($1".txt") }' TS129.txt`  and it gives the same error: `awk: PN01-0647_83096.KC_ref_129_GTS_CytoHD_na32.1.cyhd.cychp.txt makes too many open files
 input record number 1430, file 
 source line number 1`

Comment: That is not the same error I was commenting on. The error was `awk: syntax error at source line 1` from your question. wrt your new error, see Dimitre's solution using `close()` or even better just get GNU awk as it will handle that sensibly for you and your script will simply work as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{ print > ($1 ".txt") }' TS129.txt
```

UPDATE:

```
awk '{
  close(fn)
  fn = $1 ".txt"
  print >> fn
  }' TS129.txt
```

If you prefer to avoid calling close for every line:

```
awk '{
  seen[$1]++ || count++
  if (count >= limit) {
    for (fname in seen)
      close(fname ".txt")
    c = ""
    split("", seen)
    }
  print >> ($1 ".txt")
  }' limit=<number_of_open_files> TS129.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. But it gave the below shown error:`awk: PN01-0646_65836.KC_ref_129_GTS_CytoHD_na32.1.cyhd.cychp.txt makes too many open files
 input record number 1425, file 
 source line number 1`

Comment: many unique values do you have in $1?  `awk '{print $1}' file | sort -u | wc -l`

Comment: @Dimitre Radoulov: The updated code writes only the first row of the occurence of unique text in column 1. i.e. each output file has only one row.

Comment: @DimitreRadoulov : could u let me know what exactly it means: `l=<number_of_open_files>`

Comment: @user1779730, it was writing the last occurrence of $1 actually :). I've corrected the post.

Comment: @user1779730, it's the number of concurrently open files. If your awk implementation supports a maximum of 16 open files, try with l=15.

Comment: It should return 129 output files but it returns only 17 output files. So, i tried with l=16,l=14 and l=15 but it returns a similar error `awk: PN01-0646_65836.KC_ref_129_GTS_CytoHD_na32.1.cyhd.cychp.txt makes too many open files
 input record number 1424, file TS129.txt
 source line number 9`  giving only 17 output files in all cases.

Comment: Thanks!! the first updated version works now. But could you let me know why the simple awk command `awk '{print > $1".txt"}' TS129.txt ` or `awk '{print > ($1".txt")}' TS129.txt ` doesn't work in my case.

Comment: +1 for parenthesising the output file name and the close() solution but using "_" as the name of an array is a terrible idea as it obfuscates the code completely unnecessarily and you should never use the letter `l` as a variable names as it looks FAR too much like the number `1` (indistinguishable in some fonts) which again makes the code harder to read for zero benefit.

Comment: @user1779730, the first version in my post doesn't work, because your awk implementation cannot open more than 10 open files concurrently.