# concatenate a variable and string (awk, macos version)

Tags: awk

I can use the following command to split a BED file into multiple BED files based on chromosome number in the first column.

```
awk -F"\t" '{print >  $1}' sample.BED
```

If I want to add file extension to each file as ".bed" as in $1".bed", it gives me syntax error. How do I fix that?

```
awk -F"\t" '{print >  $1".bed"}' sample.BED
```

Comment: Use: `awk -F"\t" '{print > ($1".bed")}' sample.BED`

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be an easy solution :)

Comment: @anubhava It's short, but a complete answer, and it deservers being posted as such. Why post it just as a comment?

Comment: @anubhava Oh, I see. I haven't noticed it was closed _that_ fast. :)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21093626/1745001 (and various other questions).

Comment: Someone previously commented if it was a typo. No it's not I have checked multiple times. If it matters: awk version is 20200816 on my macOS 11.4. An the error is: awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>> {print>$1".bed" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: It is a typo in as much as the required syntax to have an expression on the right side of output (or input) redirection is `print>($1".bed")` and that's not what you typed. What you typed, `print>$1".bed"`, is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ed Morton: I do not want to go into semantics of it, but your point is well taken. I should have not assumed that sample codes on the internet had the proper syntax. I am happy to learn the proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @anubhava said in the comment section, you can simply add parentheses to make it work:

```
awk -F"\t" '{print > ($1".bed")}' sample.BED
```

It's important to keep in mind that `print` without parameters defaults to `print $0` and the `>` redirection only allow one argument, thus the need of parentheses.

*I'm posting the answer as a Community Wiki without earning any reputation. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)*